# Configure WCF service to access from Internet

Tags: c#, wcf

I am new to the web world and have developed a service library, and I intend to host it in a Windows form application, and I need to be able to access the service through the internet and I cannot identify the problem. I have redirected the port in the Reuter and the firewall disabled, but it throws an error System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException… anybody can help me with this?

**my appconfig**

```html
<configuration>
  <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework"
          type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
          requirePermission="false"/>
    </configSections>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basic_bindingSettings" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ws_bindingSettings" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="GCService.Service1">
        <endpoint address=""
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ws_bindingSettings"
          name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="GCService.IService1" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.100:28615/GCService/Service1" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**Run Server**

```
                    Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.1.100:28615/GCService/Service1");
                ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(GCService.Service1), baseAddress);
```

The ip 192.168.1.100 is the ip of the Local pc

**Client**

```
    EndpointAddress uri = new EndpointAddress("http://fabianwesling.dynu.com:28615/GCService/Service1");
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client ws = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client("WSHttpBinding_IService1", uri);
    ws.GetProducts();
```

Comment: I update my reply.

Answer (score 0):

First, the serviceHost on the server side should look like this:

```
 ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ConsoleApp10.Test));
 serviceHost.Open();
```

Because you have configured the baseaddress of the service in the configuration file, there is no need to configure it here, and the service must be turned on.

According to the information you provided, I found that your client uses a proxy class.The URI of the call should be the same as the address of the service endpoint:

```
EndpointAddress uri = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:28615/GCService/Service1");
ServiceReference1.TestClient testClient = new ServiceReference1.TestClient("WSHttpBinding_IService1", uri);
```

In fact, if the proxy class added through the service reference can directly create testClient, as shown below:

```
ServiceReference1.TestClient testClient = new ServiceReference1.TestClient();
```

So your client's EndpointAddress should look like this:

```
EndpointAddress uri = new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.1.100:28615/GCService/Service1");
```

**UPDATE**

If your WCF server and client are connected via the Internet, please make sure that the baseaddress of the WCF server is your real IP in the Internet.If you are using an intranet address such as 192.x.x.x, the client cannot find the service.

Comment: Thanks for answering. For local accesses it works perfect, but if I want to access through the internet, I can't do it ... try to put the real IP or a url of some dns server, in the base server, it doesn't even start the service because it can't find the metadata

Comment: Could not start the service?what error it reported?

Comment: Make sure your IP can be successfully accessed on the public Internet.

Comment: The service with local access works, but with problems accessing from the internet, you cannot find the service. I put the host url http://fabianwesling.dynu.com:28615/GCService/Service1
, I also opened the port on the router, deactivate the firewall of the router and Windows but keep throwing error "There was no end listening at http://fabianwesling.dynu.com:28615/GCService/Service1 that could accept the message. The cause is usually an incorrect SOAP address or action" ... So I must keep investigating because you can't find my service from the internet

Comment: The endpoint address can only be a URI, we cannot use a domain name as an endpoint address.